# What is the x-incap-sess-cookie-hdr header?

Tags: http, web, server, http-headers

I've seen an HTTP header called x-incap-sess-cookie-hdr Her are some examples:

`x-incap-sess-cookie-hdr: IfBmOyLQ2RLSl9UHsx97BvdpPGUAAAAAWwDOZlrDvW75HkdClD+7bQ== x-incap-sess-cookie-hdr: xOY/WoLX4VbSl9UHsx97BglqPGUAAAAAGF9u4P/84uSz+FZE3SuMdA==` 
its value changes with every refresh, What is this header?

i tried googling for this header multiple times but found no information about it.